# Place a document at the end but evaluate it at the beginning

Tags: macros

I would like to collect certain `\newcommand`s in an appendix, so that each one can have a section explaining itself. However, if I put this appendix at the end of the file, then I can't call the commands in the middle of my text because they won't be defined yet.

Is there any way to force LaTeX to scan a file and execute only the command definitions in it?

Comment: Hi! As it stands now, your question is not quite understandable. Please, show a [minimal (non-)working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), and show (again by a short example) what output exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @tohecz Alright, I will try to provide an MWE when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that should get you started.  Place your `\newcommand`s along with the description in `MyPreamble.sty`.  The format of this file is

```
\newcommand*{\CommandName}{... command text ...}%
\begin{CommandDescription}
    ... the description of what this macro does goes here ...
\end{CommandDescription}
```

In the preamble you `\include` this file via `\InputOnlyNewcommands{MyPreamble.sty}`, which ignores the description of the macros, and only defines the `\newcommand`s.  In the main body you can use these macros as you want. At the *end* of the document you can have an appendix with these commands and their description via `\InputIgnoringNewcommands{MyPreamble.sty}`.

In the example below I define three commands along with a description of what they do.

[image]

### Notes:

- Not sure how to eliminate the quote at the beginning of the command name in the appendix.
- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) was *only* used to package this example into a fully compilable example. It is not needed in your real example.
- This *only* works with `\newcommand`. That is you can not use `\def`, `\renewcommand`, `\providecommand`, or any of the equivalent macros from [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyPreamble.sty}
    \newcommand*{\Bold}[2][black]{\textbf{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}%
    \begin{CommandDescription}
        This macro makes the text parameter bold.
    \end{CommandDescription}
    
    \newcommand*{\BoldBlue}[1]{\Bold[blue]{#1}}%
    \begin{CommandDescription}
        This macros makes the text parameter bold, and also in blue.
    \end{CommandDescription}
    
    \newcommand*{\BoldRedItalics}[1]{\textit{\Bold[red]{#1}}}%
    \begin{CommandDescription}
        This macros makes the text parameter bold, italicized, and also in red.
    \end{CommandDescription}
\end{filecontents*}

\NewEnviron{CommandDescription}[1]{}{}%

\newcommand{\InputOnlyNewcommands}[1]{%
    \RenewEnviron{CommandDescription}{}{}%
    \input{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\InputIgnoringNewcommands}[1]{%
    \RenewEnviron{CommandDescription}{%
        \BODY\par
    }{%
    }%
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\newcommand}{%
        s%    #1 = optional star
        m%    #2 = macro name
        O{0}% #3 = number of parameters (optional, defaults to 1)
        o%    #4 = default value of optional parameter
        m%    #5 = code that was to be executed
    }{%
        \medskip\par\noindent%
        \Bold{\string##2:}
    }%
    \input{#1}%
}%


\InputOnlyNewcommands{MyPreamble.sty}

\begin{document}


\section{Body}
Make \Bold{this bold.}

And in color: \BoldBlue{blue.}

And in color with italics: \BoldRedItalics{red.}


\section{Appendix}
\InputIgnoringNewcommands{MyPreamble.sty}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I know what you want. Thanks to @PeterGrill and 
[How display LaTeX code in LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/how-display-latex-code-in-latex-document/4098#4098) this now works:

```
% preamble.tex
%
% commands here, documented with comments

% \foo does whatever
\newcommand{\foo}{whatever}
```

Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\input{preamble} % define your macros

\begin{document}

\section{Contents}
Use macro \foo{}.

\section{Commands I used} % document your macros

   \verbatiminput{preamble}

\end{document}
```

You won't have LaTeX formatting for your macro documentation. Peter Grill's solution does that.

**Edit:** This question/answer is related to the naive construction of [quines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) (see [Self-replicating (La)TeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91678/self-replicating-latex-document)). I use the idiom with `\jobname` to append `TeX` source for homework questions to the questions so that students have a template to start with:

```
% Math 370 hw2
%
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%% create an environment for theorems
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
The amount by which the sum of the angles of a spherical triangle
exceeds $\pi$ is proportional to the area of the triangle.
\end{thm}

\verbatiminput{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tested that this actually works?  Also, please post a complete compilable code example.

Comment: @PeterGrill oops. My thinko. I will leave this faulty answer up for a while to see whether it's what the OP wants, and as a suggestion to someone who can do it right. I'll delete it soon.