# Creating a Droste Effect

Tags: floats, rendering, recursion

Is there any way to achieve a [Droste effect](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAGahUKEwir7vzO55bGAhVCbhQKHfGtAGM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3Ftitle%3DDroste_effect&ei=y3KBVevcFMLcUfHbgpgG&usg=AFQjCNE7BPzvQuBY9S0M2aiQOJNimyZ2FQ&sig2=bcC5JLnr90CZ7-r4HEGgzw&bvm=bv.96041959,d.ZGU) in LaTeX?

For instance, I'd like to generate a floating figure that contains a rendering of the page it is included in.

Comment: Welcome. Yes there are...

Comment: Is this what you have in mind? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234399/7883

Comment: pretty much, thanks. now I need to figure how to get a single page in that box...

Comment: I have to admit that I don't exactly understand how to reproduce the same thing without the picture environment, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example using `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Drost effect}
\author{Droste}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]

\IfFileExists{\jobname-copy.pdf}{
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \framebox{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth,page=1]{\jobname-copy}}
    \caption{Droste effect}
  \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

Repeat the following commands:

```
pdflatex document.tex
cp document.pdf document-copy.pdf
```

After some iterations, you get:

[image]