# Text along a curve in Metapost

Tags: diagrams, tex-core, plain-tex, metapost

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get text along a curve in Metapost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MetaPost package [textpath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpath) may be what you are looking for.

Some time ago, I've used this package to draw [this picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234399/amusing-exercise-ouroboros-file-output-of-tex-includes-itself-recursively-ad/234453#234453), on this website. Of course, the corresponding code is written along it.

Comment: Thanks. This should do the trick.